# Facebook Request Dialog - Invite to External Website

Tags: facebook

FB.init({ 
      appId:'Application ID', cookie:true, 
      status:true, xfbml:true 
    });

```
FB.ui({ method: 'apprequests', message: 'Here is a new Requests dialog...'});
```

How to redirect the user to my external website rather than the Canvas Page inside facebook?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple posts about this online that suggest making a dummy canvas page that sets

```
window.location.top = 'yoursiteurl'
```

... but this does not seem satisfactory to me. Facebook docs are wildly unclear about whether external website ("Facebook Connect") devs are encouraged to use requests.

Comment: http://af-design.com/blog/2011/02/17/using-facebook-requests-to-promote-a-website/